# Electric current injected to ionized gas around laser beam or electron beam to make miles high ham radio antenna

Tags: antenna

I found there was a technology which uses air plasma around electron beam or laser beam and it is about injecting current in to this plasma to make far away bombs explode  or damage car electronic, or destroy nuclear missiles.

This technology can be scaled up but I am interested in miles high laser or electron beam which used as ham radio antenna.

I found 5 dollars worth of green lasers can beam 10-20 miles far away and I want to use a beam which was extremely cheap to obtain.

Can you tell me which technology hardware is the most suitable for ham radio operators?

Comment: You've picked yourself a very difficult task.  [This paper](https://cradpdf.drdc-rddc.gc.ca/PDFS/unc285/p805729_A1b.pdf) mentions very high voltage and a very intense, strongly focused laser beam.  It also mentions a transmit time of 2 milliseconds - that's the lifetime of the plasma antenna.

Comment: your question belongs here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: To ionize air requires something like an extremely powerful ultraviolet laser beam. Your cheap DPSS green laser is not going to ionize anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work. To ionize air with a laser needs insane power levels usually obtained by pulsing a laser very rapidly and dumping joules in femtoseconds. 
However, there is such a thing as a [plasma antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_antenna)

> Early practical examples of the technology used discharge tubes to
>   contain the plasma and are referred to as ionized gas plasma antennas.
>   Ionized gas plasma antennas can be turned on and off and are good for
>   stealth and resistance to electronic warfare and cyber attacks.
>   Ionized gas plasma antennas can be nested such that the higher
>   frequency plasma antennas are placed inside lower frequency plasma
>   antennas. Higher frequency ionized gas plasma antenna arrays can
>   transmit and receive through lower frequency ionized gas plasma
>   antenna arrays. This means that the ionized gas plasma antennas can be
>   co-located and ionized gas plasma antenna arrays can be stacked.
>   Ionized gas plasma antennas can eliminate or reduce co-site
>   interference. Smart ionized gas plasma antennas use plasma physics to
>   shape and steer the antenna beams without the need of phased arrays.